# Trying to add a growth percent to every column to the right of first non NA column

Tags: r

I am trying to show a small growth rate (2%) for prescription volumes across certain diseases based in the rollout schedule of enable support for that disease. Like:
[image]

where **prevcol+2%** is what I'm trying to compute for the whole df. I'm just growing my skills into loops, so I have tried:

```
ii <- 3:18
for (val in ii) {
  HOSPITAL[,val+1] <- HOSPITAL[val]+HOSPITAL[val]*.02
}
```

I feel like maybe I need some type of "If target is NA, ignore, but if not apply the function? Since it works for the rows where there is a figure in the first column, but none where the first column is NA and the first number is further down the schedule (columns to the right)

Any help is appreciated.  I'm new to stackoverflow, so forgive any newbie mistakes on the Q.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Why the diagonal values don't need to be 2% more?